# Не могу создать экземпляр JFactory в joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, php

Переписываю компонент для joomla 2.5.6 с версии 1.5. В модуле шаблона вида (/site/views/vopros/tmpl/default.php) не могу создать экземпляр класса JFactory.

```
$session = new JFactory;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class JFactory in Z:\home\localhost\www\muzeum\components\com_vopros\views\vopros\tmpl\default.php on line

Как можно разрешить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вы походу создаете абстрактный класс, который создать впринципе нельзя.

Comment: Хм. Действительно. Посмотрел в реализацию класса в 1.5 и 2.5, в новой версии класс стал абстрактным